# Send Data To PHP Through Python

Tags: php, python, post, get

I'm having trouble while sending data to PHP script through python

if i try with browser then data is posting but if i try with python script it is not posting any data and no error is shown

i have tried using headers, get instead of post

PHP:

```php
$q = @$_GET['q'];
if($q) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO data VALUES ('', '".$q."')";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Posted";
   } else {
      echo "cannot post";
   }
}
```

PYTHON:

```py
import requests
payload = {'q': 'some-data'}
r = requests.post('http://example.com/store.php', params=payload)
```

Comment: you should be using a requests.get already in php you're expecting a get. Get are type http://example.com/store.php?q=somedata

Answer (score 0):

Your Python `requests` method needs to match the one used by your PHP script to process the data.

You are currently using **POST** method - `requests.post()` - in your Python script, while trying to retrieve the data sent in the query string on the PHP end with $_**GET**(). That won't work.

You need to stay consistent...

In your python script use a 'GET' request:

```
r = requests.get('http://example.com/store.php', params=payload)
```

You can then process the data with PHP using:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
```

*By the way, some free advice, do not use @ to suppress errors in PHP, it's bad practice.*

Comment: i tried it but still nothing happened.

when i use `print(r.text)`
it shows **<noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>**